# jQuery ajax tries to send cross domain and gets 403 foribben but its on the same domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to do an ajax call to my php file on the same server. I found a url fetching script similar to Facebook to get links.
http://wakeupzee.netai.net/99points/facebook_url_extracting/
Works pretty good actually. Anyway, I want to save the info it's extracting to the DB. When I pull the src of the img link, somehow Im getting a 403 forbidden and I think it's trying to use the extracted URL even though Firebug show it's submitting my php file. It thinks the other domain is trying to submit against my php file. How can I get it to just recognize all my variable as text in the post?

Here is similar code I'm using.

```
jQuery("form#submit_ProPost").submit(function() {

var mem_id     = jQuery('#mem_id').attr('value');
var per_id     = jQuery('#per_id').attr('value');
var comment     = jQuery('#procomment').attr('value');
var action     = jQuery('#action').attr('value');
var vimg = jQuery('.linkimg').attr('src');
var uval = jQuery('.lurl').html();
var dval = jQuery('.ldesc').html();
var tval = jQuery('.ltitle').html();
var act_id    = ('1');  
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/modify.php",
        data: "mem_id="+ mem_id +"& per_id="+ per_id +"& comment="+ comment +"& action="+ action +"& act_id="+ act_id  +"& vimg="+ vimg +"& tval="+ tval +"& dval="+ dval +"& uval="+ uval,
        success: function(response){
            //do stuff here             
            }   
        });                  
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: You might want to look up the "serialize" function in jQuery.

Comment: Also, you definitely need to be wrapping those values in `encodeURIComponent calls - unless you absolutely know that they're "clean" from a URL standpoint.

Comment: just a quick note ... swapping all those jQuery() for $() will save you a lot of typing and your users some downloading ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Set `data` as an object

```
{
    "mem_id": mem_id,
    "per_id": per_id,
    "comment": comment,
    // etc
}
```

Comment: I really couldn't get that to work. It seemed it didn't like http:// in the string for some reason. Once I stripped that it would go through. Very weird. I can add that back after extraction from the db but it should be able to work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Things seem to be in order here ... open up your browser and go directly to that link, see if it is still 403 forbidden.  If it is then the problem is with permissions set on your webserver file structure (which is what I suspect is happening).  Let us know what happens ...